# Is there a token for contribution type?

Tags: civicontribute, tokens

There seems to be tokens for all sorts of contribution things but not for the financial type.   Maybe I'm missing it somewhere.

We're doing tax letters and the type ends up being the fund the people donated to, which we'd like to include in the letter.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I had tried the obvious but must have had a typo.  It is there but it isn't listed in the list of tokens. It's {contribution.financial_type}.  Should it be listed?  If so, it looks like a bug.

It didn't take much make it show.  In my test version I hacked SelectValues.php and added financial type to the contribution token array.  If I looked at the latest versions of that file it doesn't seem to be there either.

Answer (score 1):

This token {latestcontribs.financial_type}
From this extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken
works for the online receipt

Comment: Pretty sure it comes from https://civicrm.org/extensions/nzcofuzioncivitoken

Comment: Thanks. I updated the answer. And thanks for the great extension

Answer (score 0):

In the Contributions - Receipt (off-line) default template I see this line: `{ts}Financial Type{/ts}: {$formValues.contributionType_name}`.  Will that work (or some variation), even if it's not in response to a particular form being filled out?

Comment: Sadly it doesn't.  The off-line receipt is generated against a form.  The form  here doesn't have that value.  I'm doing the standard generate thank yous letters from a find contributions query.  I'm guessing I'm going to have to write a custom token thing.  It's just surprising that token doesn't exist.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but I this works (in the offline email) for me: {if $formValues.contributionType_name eq 'Event Fee'}Do something{/if} I've also got it working for custom financial types I've added. Also works by financial type ID, I just chose name to make it clearer in the email what I was doing ;)