# Smarty does not display database fields

Tags: civicontribute, smarty, system-workflow-messages

As a workflow message for a contribution confirmation, i use the following template. All values are displayed, except $financial_type_id and $source. Both stay empty in the output table. How come only those two are not displayed, while the others are? When I use total_amount (a database field) instead of amount (not a database field), the output is also empty.

```
{capture assign=headerStyle}colspan="2" style="text-align: left; padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; background-color: #eee;"{/capture}
{capture assign=labelStyle }style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; background-color: #f7f7f7;"{/capture}
{capture assign=valueStyle }style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999;"{/capture}

    <table style="border: 1px solid #999; margin: 1em 0em 1em; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%;">
    <tr><th {$headerStyle}>
        Detail Contribution
    </th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td {$labelStyle}>{ts}Financial type{/ts}</td>
        <td {$valueStyle}>{$financial_type_id}</td> <!-- IS EMPTY -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td {$labelStyle}>{ts}Total Amount{/ts}</td>
        <td {$valueStyle}>{$amount|crmMoney:$currency}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td {$labelStyle}>Year</td>
        <td {$valueStyle}>{$source}</td> <!-- IS EMPTY -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td {$labelStyle}>{ts}Receive Date{/ts}</td>
        <td {$valueStyle}>{$receive_date|truncate:10:''|crmDate}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td {$labelStyle}>{ts}Receipt Date{/ts}</td>
        <td {$valueStyle}>{$receipt_date|truncate:10:''|crmDate}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td {$labelStyle}>{ts}Transaction #{/ts}</td>
        <td {$valueStyle}>{$trxn_id}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Try prefixing the blank ones with contribution, e.g. $contribution.financial_type_id

Comment: @Dement. Thanks for the suggestion. Adding "contribution" as you suggested, did not help. The values stay empty.

Comment: This question seems similar? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8905/is-there-a-token-for-contribution-type. Maybe without the $ or see the part about formValues.

Comment: @Demert. All the suggestions did not work. {$formValues.xxx} is for the offline confirmation (based on a form). The online version is the template used with a query (for instance, the n latest imported contributions),and is no form. I tried the different names {$contribution.xxx}, {contribution.xxx} where xxx = "financial_type" or  "financial_type_id". Also {financial_type_id} without $. Same problem with "source" or "paidBy".